# multiple select statement in single OleDbCommand is not working

Tags: oledbcommand

I am trying to select data from 2 access tables using a single command object. here is my code-

```
using (OleDbCommand cmdCommand=new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmdCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdCommand.CommandText = "select * from tableA;select * from tableB";
    cmdCommand.Connection = Connection;
    using (OleDbDataAdapter daData=new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
       daData.SelectCommand = cmdCommand;
       Connection.Open(); daData.Fill(ds); Connection.Close();
    }
 }
```

But it throws exception "Characters found after end of sql statement."
Any suggesstion?

Comment: use stored procedure or something like that, after the semicolon of first query it wont read anything to be executed

Comment: rather create a single query to get data from both tables using joins, because in Access i dont think there are stored procedures to execute multiple queries